# Can I view the resolved config Apache is using?

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd

Is there a way to view the final "effective" config a running Apache instance is using after resolving any/all includes and the like?

I'm looking at a config that has a web of includes and suspect some of the issues I'm having are related to the order in which everything falls into place. I think it's apachectl that can validate a config has no syntax errors, but I'm wondering if I can go a step further and somehow output the fully assembled config. Any advice (short of cleaning up this mess of includes that should never have been allowed to happen)?

**Update:** I haven't read through the docs yet, but could [mod_info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html) potentially help me with this?

Comment: This belongs on server fault I'm afraid

Comment: mod_info appears to get you close via ?config. Dumping the configuration on startup:
If the config define -DDUMP_CONFIG is set, mod_info will dump the pre-parsed configuration to stdout during server startup. Pre-parsed means that directives like <IfDefine> and <IfModule> are evaluated and environment varialbles are replaced. However it does not represent the final state of the configuration. In particular, it does not represent the merging or overriding that may happen for repeated directives.
This is roughly equivalent to the ?config query.

Comment: related :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152943
https://superuser.com/questions/922869
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129026
https://serverfault.com/questions/425894
https://serverfault.com/questions/696164
https://serverfault.com/questions/500329
https://serverfault.com/questions/489018
https://serverfault.com/questions/42539

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_info.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/invoking.html